# Replacing \n with <br> between specified tags using python's re.sub()

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a series of tab-separated html snippets in a `.tsv` file. Here's an example of one of the snippets:

```py
<li> 
  <p>Create a list of letters, <code>lst</code> from the string <code>strng = &quot;abc&quot;</code>.</p> 

  <ul> 
    <li>Use the list constructor, <code>list()</code>, to create a list from a string.</li> 
  </ul> 

  <pre>
      <code class='language-python' lang='python'>
      strng = &quot;abc&quot; 
      lst = list(a) 
      #lst = [&#39;a&#39;, &#39;b&#39;, &#39;c&#39;] 
    </code>
  </pre> 

</li>
```

I would like to replace the newlines, `\n`, with line breaks, `<br>`, **only** in between the `<pre> <code class='language-python' lang='python'>` and  `</code> </pre>` tags, using a regular expression and `re.sub()`.

I've tried creating a the following regular expression to match the desired newlines:

```
(?<=<pre><code)\r\n?|\n(?<=</pre></code>)
```

However, the above regular expression doesn't match any newline characters from the snippet. Although, if I remove the positive look-behind, then the regex *does* match the newlines I need (at least for the snippet I've shown in this post, a;though that won't be true for all inputs).

```
(?<=<pre><code)\r\n?|\n
```

Can a regex that will catch all newlines between between the tags: `<pre> <code class='language-python' lang='python'>` and  `</code> </pre>` in all possible snippets?

**EDIT**: These snippets don't use "full" html. They're actually meant to be exported to a flashcard application [mnemosyne](https://mnemosyne-proj.org/). Each of these snippets represents one flashcard, which will always have the same controlled html structure (defined by me.) So, there wouldn't be any consequences to using regex in this case. Also, the html renderer used by mnemosyne doesn't line break within `<pre>` tags, so I'm trying to do it manually with `<br>`.

Comment: why not use a xml parser ?

Comment: Please don't do this (parsing HTML with regex)! [You'll summon TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/364696). Parse with BeautifulSoup or the like, and modify the text inside the elements you care about.

Comment: So I’m going to ask that question people don’t like: why, given that `<pre>` normally does that job? Is this part of a workaround where your real problem is getting rid of common indentation?

Comment: These snippets don't use "full" html. They're actually just files meant to be exported to a flashcard application [mnemosyne](https://mnemosyne-proj.org/). Each of these snippets represents one flashcard, which will always have the same, controlled html structure (defined by me.) So, there wouldn't be any consequences to using regex in this case.

Comment: @Ry- The html renderer in mnemosyne doesn't line break for <pre>, so I needed to manually line-break. Should I include this information in the original post?

Comment: @David: Sure, as a short sentence in introducing the problem, it couldn’t hurt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re in a situation where you can be confident enough of your input to go ahead with using regular expressions instead of an HTML parser, one simpler way might be to replace in two steps using a function as a replacement in `re.sub`:

```
def nl2br(text):
    return "<br>".join(text.splitlines())


re.sub("(<pre><code[^>]*>)(.*?)(</code></pre>)", lambda m: m.group(1) + nl2br(m.group(2)) + m.group(3), html, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

(might want `\s*` between `<pre>`/`<code>` and `</code>`/`</pre>`.)

Answer (score 1):

If all of the files are just HTML snippets, meaning parse-able XML, the best way to do this would be just to use an XML parser:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmlDocument = minidom.parse('file.tsv')
codeItem = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('code')
codeItem.firstChild.replaceWholeText(codeItem.firstChild.nodeValue.replace('\n', '<br>'))
print xmlDocument.toxml()
```